# Is $\mathcal O_X(U) \cong \mathcal O_X(V)$ when $U,V$ both contain the same collection of associated points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a locally Noetherian scheme and  $U, V$ be two open subsets of $X$ containing the same associated points of $X$. (the associated points of $X$ lying in $U$ are the same as the associated points of $X$ lying in $V$). It is well-
known that there are injections

$$\mathcal O_X(U) \to \prod_{associated~p \in U}\mathcal O_{X,p},$$
$$\mathcal O_X(V) \to \prod_{associated~p \in V}\mathcal O_{X,p}.$$

Does it follows from here that $\mathcal O_X(U) \cong \mathcal O_X(V)$ as two rings?

Comment: For those who haven't seen the term before, here is ["associated points" at the stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02OI)

Comment: I do not think this is true, I know for an integral domain the only associated point is the generic point. So for example if we take $X= Spec(\mathbb{C}[x])$ and let $U=(0)$ and $V=X$, then I think these satisfy your conditions, yet we do not have the isomorphism.

Comment: This is the algebraic definition. I want to add the geometry definition which is equivalent: associated points of an affine scheme are generic points of irreducible components of support of fuctions. The associated points of locally Noetherian schemes are defined locally,

Comment: @sheelstueber The U in you comment is not open I think

Comment: @TiWen yes you are correct my mistake, but I think we could possibly slightly modify my example to find a counter example to your statement.  For example, possibly take $U=D(f)$ for some function $f$

Answer (score 1):

No, this is totally false.  For instance, when $X$ is integral, the only associated point is the generic point, which is contained in every nonempty open set.  So your question would be whether $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ are isomorphic for all nonempty open subsets $U,V\subseteq X$.  This is obviously false (e.g., let $X=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$, let $U=X$, and let $V=D(2)$, so $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(V)=\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$).